# How do I turn my partitions into a Windows-like C and D disk?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Based on my fruitless googling I must have misunderstood how partitions work.

I have 1 hard drive on which I installed Ubuntu 18.04. I've then decided I want to split my 1 partition into 2. I did this with the help of a bootable Ubuntu USB stick and GParted

What I expected to happen afterwards was that I would have something like the Windows disk C and disk D which would basically just separate my storage.

How do I get from where I am now to having that Windows-like situation?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*Windows-like*" in this context. I use both OS every day -- they are different; we must respect those differences to avoid frustration. Do you mean that you want your data on the other partition (good idea)? Do you mean that you want to install applications on the other partition (bad idea)? Separate storage for shared media like movies and music? Are you trying to separate services or Virtual Machines? Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. I must agree with @user535733. As your question is stated right now, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes to your first question.

I would essentially like them to work like two big folders. Like in Windows you might have various files in C://... and various files in D://...

Is that clear?

Comment: Thanks Bruni, sorry I thought my question was clear. Does my last comment clarify what I mean?

Comment: I think you are saying that you want to store your personal data (email, documents, projects, movies, etc.) on sda2 instead of sda1. You don't want any personal data on sda1. Is that accurate?

Comment: Almost, I would like sda2 to be additional storage. I still like to be able to keep data on sda1 and move some to sd2.

Comment: `sda`, `sda1`, `sda2`, `sdb1`, etc: that's how Ubuntu labels disks and partitions.  You can mount them and put files wherever you want, for the most part.  Maybe you are just confused?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use partitions as if they were folders - for the purposes of organization - this is generally not wise since you put artificial limits on the amount of storage. Folders are more appropriate for separating files. The sole benefit to using a separate partition is that you can potentially format them separately.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I see now what I wanted to do isn't useful.

@Nmath Understood but, if I wanted to do it just as an exercise how would I do it?

Comment: Think what you wanted to done, in Linux have one partition as /(root) and one partition as /home(data)  Root can be about 25 to 40GBs and home would be the rest, if you wanted that much.  There are ways of separating /home from your sda1 partition, but safest for now would be to move your data(videos, pictures) to sda2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux, there is no complicated notion of extra drive letters. You only have to understand file paths to locate any file available to you.

In Linux, everything is a file. There is one single starting folder, the "root directory", which simply is represented by "/". Many folders exist in that root directory. Most contain system files. One folder is called "home". Its full path is "/home". There, the user's home folders live. So if your login is "david", there will be a folder "david" in the "/home" folder. The full pathname to that folder is "/home/david".

Partitions that contain a file system, i.e. what Windows would see as a "different drive letter" are, in linux, integrated into the file system. This is done by **mounting** the partition into a folder of the file system.

USB drives that you plug in are automatically mounted in a folder under "/media". In your example, these drives would be mounted under "/media/david". The file manager shows such mounted drives in a "windowesque" manner by showing an icon for them in the left pane.

Your /dev/sda1 is your root partition. You will never be able to see that as a separate storage volume. Navigate to its contents through "Other locations" in the file manager, then "Computer".

You could have your /dev/sda2 appear as a "drive letter" if you label it. If a partition has a label, that label will be used to display the partition in File manager. So set the label to for example "D" and the partition will show up in the left pane as "D".

If you give the partition a name, it will be shown with that name.